# Laravel - Check if in many to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, relationship

A user can save ingredients to a shopping list. Now, when a User is logged in and visit a recipe, the shopping list widget is showing him, which ingredients he already have on his list, and that's my problem.

Here I'm getting all ingredients for the recipe:

```
$recipe = Recipe::find($id);
$recipe->load('ingredients');
```

Working fine with a foreach on $recipe->ingredients

And here I'm gettingthe shopping list a user has for this recipe, if he has one:

```
if(Auth::check()) {
  $list = ShoppingList::with('ingredients')->where('recipe_id',$id)->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->get();   
//... 
}
```

And here I'm trying to check, if an saved ingredient is on the shopping list:

```
            foreach($recipe->ingredients as $i) {
            foreach($list as $l) {
                $ingredient = Ingredients::where('id','=',$l->ingredients_id)->get();
                $i->isAdded = (count($ingredient) > 0) ? 1 : 0;
            }

        }
```

But somehow that's totally wrong. What am I missing?

**Relationships:**
Recipe:

```
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User','user_id');
}
public function lists() {
        return $this->hasMany('ShoppingList','recipe_id');
}

public function ingredients() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Ingredients','ingredients_recipe','recipe_id','ingredients_id')->withPivot('amount');
}
```

Shopping List:

```
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User','id');
}
public function recipe() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Recipe','recipe_id');
}
public function ingredients() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Ingredients','shopping_list_ingredients','shopping_list_id','ingredients_id')
                    ->withPivot(array('unit','amount'))
                    ->withTimestamps();
}
```

Ingredients:

```
    public function recipes() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Recipe','ingredients_recipe','recipe_id','ingredients_id')->withPivot('amount');
}
public function lists() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('ShoppingList','shopping_list_ingredients','shopping_list_id','ingredients_id')
        ->withPivot(array('unit','amount'))
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your explanation is a bit cloudy with this code, but the point is, that you need to find missing ingredients and add them to the shopping list, is it correct?

For this you can use Collection's diff method:

```
// retrieve collection of the ingredients for a recipe
$recipe = Recipe::with('ingredients')->find($recipeId);

// retrieve collection of the ingredients for a shopping list
$list = ShoppingList::with('ingredients')->find($recipeId);

// find the ingredients for the recipe that are not on the list already
// return Collection of Ingredient models
$missingIngredients = $recipe->ingredients->diff($list->ingredients);

// and ingredients on both list and recipe
$missingIngredients = $recipe->ingredients->intersect($list->ingredients);
```

Comment: yes and no. I need to find the ingredients, which are already on the shopping list of the user for this recipe. Let's say, the recipe has 3 ingredients (sausage, cheese, bread). The user created a list jsut with cheese and sausage. So need to know, which ID's are already on the list (ingredient->isAdded = 1 or 0). Is that better? :)

Comment: acutally is the same code you did, but just change the variables, right?

Comment: If you need to find those ingredients that are in both list and recipe then use intersect method instead of diff

Comment: Perfect! Once again! Thank you very much!